# finite difference method for reaction diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I am implementing a finite difference scheme for the following PDE:
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)
$$
with the nonflux boundary condition and a given initial condition. The scheme is backward in time and central in space(which should be unconditionally stable) as
$$
\frac{u^{k+1}_i-u^k_i}{\Delta t}=\frac{u^{k+1}_{i-1}-2u^{k+1}_{i}+u^{k+1}_{i+1}}{\Delta x^2}+f(u_i^k)
$$
however, I am not getting the correct order of convergence, i.e. first order in time and second order in space. And the scheme is not convergence(actually blows up...). I am just wondering is there any special condition I need to be careful on reaction-diffusion equations? because I downgrade the case into heat equation
$$
u_t=u_{xx}
$$
with the same boundary condition and then I am getting the expected order of convergence.

The update scheme is
$$
A\mathbf{u}^{k+1} = u^{k+1}_i - \alpha (u^{k+1}_{i-1}-2u^{k+1}_{i}+u^{k+1}_{i+1}) = u^k_i + \Delta t f(u_i^k)
$$
where $A$ has diagonal = $1+2\alpha$ with off diagonals = $-alpha$ and the $A(1,2)=A(N,N-A)=-2\alpha$. For the heat equation, there's no $\Delta t f(u_i^k)$ on the right-hand side.

To take care of the nonflux boundary condition, I also used second-order central in space as
$$
\frac{u_{-1}-u_1}{2\Delta x}=0
$$

I do suspect the boundary is somehow wrong because I plotted each time stamp to see how spatial solution evolves and I do observe errors getting larger at the right end. But I can't think of other ways to take care of the boundaries... any suggestion is appreciated!

---

update: please please update MATLAB version. I used the same scheme but with the latest MATLAB version and got the right order of convergence...

Comment: Did you do any analysis on the iteration matrix? I guess the error you said was truncation error. You had $AU_{k+1} = U_k +\Delta t f(U_k)$, but $A$ is not symmetric as in Neumann B.C., would you mind showing the step of your error estimate?

Comment: Yes $A$ is not symmetric but the condition number is not too bad. The order I mentioned is the convergence order that is if I vary dx only then the norm(numerical-true, 'infty') should follow the second-order line.